# How to get CSRF protection work with pagination?

Tags: python, django, pagination, get, django-csrf

I want to enable pagination in a search form with `CSRF` protection, so I have to add the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` `GET` parameter to the link to the previous/next page.

The url looks like this:

```
localhost:8000/myapp/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=JHgf7Cs6WgX29oOsLEpkW1w91ROVTpxXtNAgU1kSA3sDW1aUUOcXmBnxufahqfIS&q=foobar
```

Here is what I've done:

> search.html

```
<form method="get" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        {% trans "Search" %}
    </button>
</form>

......

{% include 'pagination.html' %}
```

> pagination.html

```
<a href="{# csrf_token #}?q={{ query }}&amp;?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
    <span aria-label="Previous">&larr;</span>{% trans "Previous" %}
</a>
```

What should I replace `{# csrf_token #}` with to pass the CSRF token to the next page?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need `CSRF Authentication` for a `GET` request. As explained in this [link of the official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf):

> The first defense against `CSRF` attacks is to ensure that `GET` requests (and other ‘safe’ methods, as defined by [RFC 7231#section-4.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.html#section-4.2.1)) are side effect free. Requests via ‘unsafe’ methods, such as `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`, can then be protected by following the steps below.

Furthemore, in Django version 1.11, the [`CSRF_USE_SESSIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-use-sessions) has been added, which you can use as follows ([taken from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-is-true)):

1. Include the `CSRF` token in your HTML (`{% csrf_token %}`)
2. Read the token from the DOM with JavaScript:

   ```
   {% csrf_token %} 
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // using jQuery
   var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
   </script>
   ```

and that will enable you to have the CSRF token through your session without passing it with the url.

Good luck :)